# how to show a drop down list/menu when right mouse button is pressed?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-forms-designer, gmap.net

I am trying to create such that when I click RMB a drop down list/menu is created. My definition of the drop down menu will be attached below. I am stuck at the event handler, I filtered if the even is a LMB or RMB and then I am having issues from here.

Firstly my requirement, I have designed a map when I click RMB I need a drop down so I can select suitable options.

[image]

My Drop down definition

```
this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick = new ComboBox();
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(700, 700);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 120);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.MaxLength = 5;
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Items.Add(1);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Items.Add(2);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Items.Add(3);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Items.Add(4);
        this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick.Items.Add(5);
```

And finally my event handler

```
        private void UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            double WaypointLatitude = UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
            double WaypointLongitude = UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;
            //  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(WaypointLatitude));
            //  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(WaypointLongitude));

            //  GMapOverlay NavigationWayPoint = new GMapOverlay("NavigationWayPoint");
            //  GMapMarker WayPoint = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(WaypointLatitude, WaypointLongitude), GMarkerGoogleType.orange_small);
            //  NavigationWayPoint.Markers.Add(WayPoint);
            //  UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel.Overlays.Add(NavigationWayPoint);
        }
        else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            
            //  MessageBox.Show("Right Mouse button Mouse clicked");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.UserControl_MissionPlan_MapPanel_MourseRightClick = new ComboBox();`  Struggling to understand this line of code.  If you have exceptions, you need to post them, too.

Comment: Anyway, the "control" needs to be added to a container and shown, and I don't see that code.

Comment: It seems you want a context menu. Are you sure you want a ComboBox?

Comment: I agree with Harald, this sounds exactly like a [ContextMenuStrip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=netframework-4.8) … Create a new `ContextMenuStrip`, then whatever object holds the image… select it and set its `ContextMenuStrip` property to point to your new `ContextMenuStrip`.